# Proper registering a Service Provider in Laravel 4.1 using $this->app->share()

Tags: php, laravel-4, facade, service-provider

I've written this image upload service but the problem is that I keep getting the following error.
I've tried a number of suggestions but I don't seem to get over it.

error type ReflectionException, message Class upload.image does not exist","file":"C:\xampp\htdocs\tippy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php", line 501

ImageUploadService.php

```
namespace Tippy\Services\Upload;

use Intervention\Image\Image;

use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class ImageUploadService
{
protected $directory = 'assets/img/uploads/temp';

protected $extension = 'jpg';

protected $size = 160;

protected $quality = 65;

protected $filesystem;

public function __construct(Filesystem $filesystem)
{
    $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
}   

public function enableCORS($origin)
{
    $allowHeaders = [
        'Origin',
        'X-Requested-With',
        'Content-Range',
        'Content-Disposition',
        'Content-Type'
    ];

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ' . implode(', ', $allowHeaders));
}

protected function getFullPath($path)
{
    return  public_path() . '/' . $path;
}
protected function makeFileName()
{
    return Sha1(time() . time()) . '.{$this->extension}';
}

protected function getFile($path)
{
    $this->filesytem->get($path);
}

protected function getFileSize($path)
{
    return $this->filesytem->size($path);
}

protected function getDataUrl($mime, $path)
{   
    $base = base64_encode($this->getFile($path));

    return 'data:' .  $mime . ';base64,'  $base;
}

protected function getJsonBody($filename, $mime, $path)
{
    return [
        'images' => [
            'filename'  => $filename,
            'mime'      => $mime,
            'size'      => $this->getFileSize($path),
            'dataURL'   => $this->getDataUrl($mime, $path)
        ]
    ];
}

public function handle(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $mime       = $file->getMimeType();
    $filename   = $this->makeFileName();
    $path       = $this->getFullPath($this->directory . '/' . $filename);

    $success = Image::make($file->getRealPath())
                    ->resize($this->size, $this->size, true, false)
                    ->save($path, $this->quality);

    if (! $success) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->getJsonBody($filename, $mime, $path);
}
}
```

Here is UploadServiceProvider.php

```
namespace Tippy\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Tippy\Services\Upload\ImageUploadService;

class UploadServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
public function register()
{
$this->app['upload.image'] = $this->app->share(function ($app) {
return new ImageUploadService($app['files']);
});
}
}
```

Here's my ImageUpload.php Facade

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'upload.image';  
}
```

And finally I've autoloaded the provider

```
'Tippy\Providers\UploadServiceProvider',
```

And aliased the class

```
'ImageUpload'     => 'Tippy\Facades\ImageUpload',
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Before diving into the world of Facades & Services,

You have to take a look at `PSR-0` convention. `PSR-0` tells composer how to load your classes (facades, services & the lot).

Link to useful resources:

[What is PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)

[Using a PSR-0 Directory Structure](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/46)

[Setup your own library](http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading)

Comment: I already had my classes auto-loaded with PSR-0 convention. I also have repositories which are working fine and the binding is in a service provider but this seems weird because I can't quite tell where the problem might be.

Comment: Simply remove the dot notation in the app name (`upload.image`), and go with a unique name, such as `DGImageUpload`.

Comment: I believe the dot notation is just a naming convention and should have no effect because I tried renaming it but it doesn't respond either.